# Rescaling png bitmap in android

Tags: java, android, png

So i have this image of a green ball in png format(103x104px is the size), and im trying to resize it before i draw it on the screen. Im trying this code, which i found in many threads and also in the android documentation this function is specified as exactly what i should need, but it doesnt work.

```
Bitmap a=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.example);
Bitmap b=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(a,30,30,false);
```

and then i draw it with

```
canvas.drawBitmap(b, x, y ,paint);
```

But no matter which numbers i give into the createScaledBitmap() the image is still the same on the screen.

Comment: Do you actually need a differently-sized `Bitmap`, or can you scale the `View`?  That might be easier.

Comment: I have a feeling it has something to do with your canvas because the re-sizing code looks fine.

Comment: scaling the view is not an option i think, the app is a game that runs in a single view and scaling the view would make the whole app smaller (not sure if this is correct though :D). Well but what could be wrong with canvas? the canvas part is taken from overrided onDraw method.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the solution was in the end pretty simple :D i overlooked one line in the code that i forget to erase when i decided to resize it and that line always backed it up, so this code indeed works. My fault, should have searched my code longer before posting.